# jQuery validation only works on page refresh

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-validate

I have the code in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dqk8Y/1/) on my site. The code there is exactly what is implemented on my site, with the exception that my site also has `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>` after the `<meta>` tag (as jsFiddle calls it automatically; this is present in the below code). The code works as expected on jsFiddle, but on my site the validation does not work unless the page is refreshed or the back button is clicked after the first submission. The form redirects to the `logins.php` script (blank right now), and after pressing the back button the validation works fine. I have `data-ajax="false"` on the form. What can I do so that the form validation always works, not just after refreshing or going back?

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
    <title>Welcome</title> 

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#loginForm").validate();
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        label.error {
            font-weight:bold;
            color:red;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />

</head> 
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="login">
        <div data-role="header"><h1>Log In</h1></div>
        <div data-role="content">You can use the fields below to log in to your account.<br>
        <br>
        <form action="logins.php" method="POST" id="loginForm" name="loginForm" data-ajax="false">
            <label for="email" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Email Address:</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" class="required email" minlength="5" placeholder="Email Address" />
            <label for="pass" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" value="" class="required" minlength="5" placeholder="Password" />
            <input class="submit" data-role="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form><br>
        <br>
        <a href="index.php" data-role="button" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Return to home page</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer"><h4>&copy; Me 2013</h4></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Always include your code in your question, as there's no guarantee that jsfiddle will always be there, and without it your question loses all context.

Comment: Done. Sorry, and thank you!

Comment: Can you show where the script tag is exactly?

Comment: I just updated the code pasted into the post; it's there now.

Comment: Your jsFiddle is not really an accurate test of anything since you're not using it properly.  Put the includes in the panel on the left, put the content of `body` within the HTML section, put the CSS in the CSS section, and put the jQuery in the JavaScript section.

Comment: Same thing with everything in its proper place... maybe it will help.  http://jsfiddle.net/sjbL9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html

`$(document).ready()` should not be used with jQuery Mobile. Use `$(document).bind("pageinit")` instead.

Also, jQuery Mobile 1.2 supports jQuery Core 1.8.2 (not 1.8.3).

Comment: I had tried that, but I kept it in the head when I did. I moved it to the bottom of the page (as referenced in the demo: http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/jquerymobile.html) and it's now working. Thank you so much!